# Trying to install CentOS 7 Server with manual partitioning but GUI is very different from CentOS 6

Tags: centos

When I installed on CentOS 6, to get a "headless" or command-line only server with the manual partioning I wanted I went through the below steps:

1. Choose **"Install with basic video driver"**
2. Choose type of device: **"Basic Storage Devices"**
3. Create custom layout:

   a. Click **"sda"** and create **"sda1"** and **"/boot"** partition

   b. Mark it as **"Force to be a primary partition"**

   c. Click **"sda2"** and choose to create **"LVM Volume Group"**

Then I create the **"/home"**, **"/"**, etc on the Volume Group and also choose **"Install boot loader on /dev/sda"**

But NONE of those options are available in the CentOS 7 install GUI (not the basic server and I don't even see sda1/2). How do I achieve those same settings in the new installer? The two areas I need to know are:

1. How make it a command-line server from the current options?
2. How achieve those partition choices?

Answer (score 1):

You can try [this link](http://www.tecmint.com/centos-7-installation/) with screenshot this might help you, you can select `minimal install` or `basic web-server` option for installing the server into command-line.

Answer (score 0):

1. if you google images "centos 7 software selection options" you will see a pic showing all the choices available for "Base Environment" which include "Minimal Install (basic functionality)" and "Gnome Desktop" and "Server with GUI".  My recommendation would be to do "Server with gui" because that will basically install and allow all software that could possibly be needed, then after install reboot simply do a `systemctl set-default multi-user.target` and that will give you your *command line only **server***.
2. For manual paritioning, like above reply in that link given you want to do `Custom Partitioning`.  If it says "Installation Desination Automatic Partitioning" then that's your problem, go into that section of the install and choose custom, should be intuitive from there.